# when to use to_categorical in keras

Tags: keras

Please someone explain when `keras.utils.np_utils.to_categorical` is to be used?
I understand that it converts *class vector* to *binary matrix*, probably used in **Deep Learning model**.
But if we still go ahead and use the class vector itself, and probably use `model.predict_classes` - what is the drawback?

Answer (score 17):

A classification model with multiple classes doesn't work well if you don't have classes distributed in a binary matrix.

Suppose you have three clasess, the vector goes like this:

- [1, 0, 0] = class 1
- [0, 1, 0] = class 2
- [0, 0, 1] = class 3

You use `to_categorical` to transform your training data before you pass it to your model.

If your training data uses classes as numbers, `to_categorical` will transform those numbers in proper vectors for using with models. You can't simply train a classification model without that.

Unfortunately, `predict_classes` is not documented, so it's probably better not to use it. But I suppose it does exactly the inverse operation `to_categorical` does. Your model outputs the vectors, and `predict_classes` transforms those vectors in human readable classes.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for explanation. One question though "You can't simply train a classification model without that" - Does this apply to DL problems only or in general? Because say using RandomForestClassifier in scikit learn and all, I dont remember using methods to transform data (class labels).. I have simply used the classes under a variable "y" and passed to the classifiers? Am I missing something?

Comment: Hmm... I don't know RandomForestClassifier, I've been using only Keras, and so far 100% of the classification examples do need to be in this array form. What were your class labels in that case? Notice that every different dataset you find on the internet comes in a different way, some come already prepared, some don't.

Comment: Thanks.. I guess for Keras it makes sense to do this, as we probably would be dealing with large datasets

Comment: Adding: with `Embedding` layers you can use just "indices" for classes as input. (But internally the layer will treat them as a categorical thing).

Comment: @DanielMöller :  In final layer, can I use Dense(6, activation='softmax')  for multi class classification instead of 1st using to_categorical?  If not, then whats the difference between these 2 approaches? Lets say I have 5 labels [1,2,3,4,5]. Thanks

Comment: @Neo, the final layer is something completely different from the data. You need to use `to_categorical` "in the data" if you use `softmax` "in the layer". Maybe you can try the "sparse" losses, like `"sparse_categorical_crossentropy"`, I believe they do the "to_categorical" job internally for you and you can pass data as indices instead of as one-hot.

Answer (score 12):

I know this is an old thread, but figured I'd help clarify.

The reason you want to_categorical (even on numeric labels) is due to how the relationship between your labels is understood by the algorithm.

For example, suppose you made a color classifier. You mark red as 1, blue as 2, and orange as 3.

Now you feed them into the machine learning algorithm to help decide what your input matches. The math is going to say that orange is higher than red. This obviously isn't your intent, but the network will know that orange is *greater* than red.